# How is possible to rollback 'truncate' operations on a database although it is DDL

Tags: database, ddl, rollback, truncate

I have read that 'truncte' is a DDL and also it is possible to rollback the data removed by 'truncate' . It is quite contradicting since we cant rollback any DDL statements. Can you please explain the concept?

Comment: This depends on the DBMS you are using. `TRUNCATE` _can_ be rolled back in e.g. Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the database supporting DDL to be transactional. For example IBM DB2, Ingres and PostgreSQL support this feature, but Oracle on the other hand does not (it supports something different though) - you cannot rollback a `truncate` statement in Oracle.

Here's a non-exhaustive overview of [databases supporting transactional DDL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis) created by the PostgreSQL contributors.

Edit: To answer your question, it is a common requirement to have transactional DDL. E.g. during version upgrades of software components which require a specific database schema.

And just my two cents: Many of my customers use Oracle. Now don't get me wrong, Oracle is a good database, but the lack of transactional DDL can be very annoying, because you always have to keep it in mind.

Comment: I actually think the SQL standard *does* require transactional DDL: "*If an SQL-transaction is terminated by successful execution of a <commit statement>, then all changes made to SQL-data **or schemas** by that SQL-transaction are made persistent*" and "*If an SQL-transaction is terminated by a <rollback statement> or unsuccessful execution of a <commit statement>, then all changes made to SQL-data **or schemas** by that SQL-transaction are canceled*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Huh, thanks for correcting me there. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that the SQL standard also classifies TRUNCATE as DML, not DDL